# Javascript on my page not working in iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, d3.js

I have been playing around for a few hours on my page trying to get the javascript to load on iOS. Both charts using chartjs and D3 will not load on a mobile browser (safari on ipad and iphone)

On desktop browser it works fine, and i have no JS errors in the console. What can I try? I dont really know where to start with fixing this problem as i dont know what is causing it. Here is the page:
http://coffeebreaknow.com/bean-exploring/single-origin/south-america/brazilbeans/

Comment: I get two errors when I run your page in the Chrome simulator for iPhone 6 device. one is Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null in var pieData = {} you have an object with empty properties. Try to remove this.  And second error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null" on statement document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv); .. probably divName does not exist.

Comment: Thanks, i didn't know you could do that in chrome - Finally have some direction to get it fixed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get two errors when I run your page in the Chrome simulator for iPhone 6 device. one is Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null in var pieData = {} you have an object with empty properties. Try to remove this. And second error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null" on statement document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv); .. probably divName does not exist.

Comment: Thanks the information led me to put all my javascript at the footer of my page, which fixed the issue. Weirdly, it seems on iOS the javascript was executed before the DOM was built - but not on a desktop browser.